# Maven build issue - Connection to repository refused

Tags: maven, github, maven-3

I wish to import, change, rebuild, test and push/check-in my changes to the code available [in this Github repository](https://github.com/cloudera/seismichadoop)

Currently, I do not wish to use any IDE or plug-ins for this purpose.

I installed Maven on my Windows machine and as proceeded as per the installation instructions as shown below :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\298790\My Documents\Downloads\seismichadoop-master>mvn
 -X package
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:
28+0530)
Maven home: D:\Omkar\Development\Softwares\Tools\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_20, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\Omkar\Development\Softwares\Tools\apache
-maven-3.0.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Documents and Settings\298790\.m2\settings
.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Documents and Settings\298790\.m2\repositor
y
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Doc
uments and Settings\298790\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.cloudera.seismic:seismic:jar:0.1.0: (no
ne)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.co
re, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.cloudera.seismic:seismic:jar:0.1.0
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [package]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building seismic 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-so
urces, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate
-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resou
rces, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-in
tegration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy
]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo
.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\298790\.m2\re
pository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5\maven-resources-plu
gin-2.5.pom.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.573s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 24 12:05:55 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
 dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.
apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http:/
/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refus
ed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugi
ns:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-
plugin:jar:2.5
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginD
escriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDes
criptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(D
efaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(Bu
ilderCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
 read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:ja
r:2.5
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifac
tDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
 transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/
to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.mave
n.apache.org refused
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
facts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
fact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tra
nsfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to c
entral (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.ap
ache.org refused
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(W
agonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(W
agonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.
run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Run
nableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection to http://
repo.maven.apache.org refused
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInput
Data(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:892)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:11
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.
run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnect
Exception: Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultCli
entConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedCli
entConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultR
equestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultR
equestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Abstract
HttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Abstract
HttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(A
bstractHttpClientWagon.java:746)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInput
Data(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:886)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSoc
ketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultCli
entConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        ... 15 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

I tried to access the URL for which I'm getting the connection refused error :

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org

Browsing for this directory has been disabled.

View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.
```

The pom.xml is as follows :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.cloudera.seismic</groupId>
  <artifactId>seismic</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>seismic</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.crunch</groupId>
      <artifactId>crunch</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-hadoop</id>
      <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/hadoop-job.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.cloudera.seismic.segy.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sitting behind a proxy?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Most probably you are behind proxy.

Try to do a `telnet repo.maven.apache.org 80` and probably you will find it failed to connect.

In your settings.xml, add corresponding proxy settings to tell Maven to go through the proxy to download the artifacts

```
<settings>
    .......
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>your_proxy_host</host>
            <port>your_proxy_port</port>
            <!--
            <username>proxyuser</username>
            <password>somepassword</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>*.yourdomain.com|*.yourOtherDomain.com</nonProxyHosts>
            -->
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: Hi Adrian,
That was indeed the issue - thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I'm not running behind a proxy, when I telnet I get `Escape character is '^]'` followed by `connection closed by foreign host`.

Comment: @JeroenBollen no one can help with just a statement like this.  There can be hundreds of possibilities. Raise a proper question, give details of the symptoms you faced.  Then people can probably help on that.

Comment: Fixed it already, just seemed to be maven eclipse not having properly installed the plugin.

Comment: How to identify what is my proxy host and port ?

Comment: With settings.xml configured with proxy it says `Unknown host pb-proxy.shaharma.net`

Comment: what is the settings.xml equivalent for sbt builds (as opposed to maven)

Comment: one more addition...you can have the same proxy for https as well like <protocol>https</protocol>