# boot development in hoplon not working

Tags: clojure, ubuntu-12.04, boot, hoplon

In a hoplon project, by executing: boot development, i get these errors:

```
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable
Failed to collect dependencies for [#<Dependency org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.6.0 (compile)> #<Dependency tailrecursion:boot.core:jar:2.5.1 (compile)> #<Dependency tailrecursion:boot.task:jar:2.2.4 (compile)> #<Dependency tailrecursion:hoplon:jar:5.10.23
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.6.0
↳ Caused by: Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.6.0 from/to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
```

I have boot installed on my machine. (Ubuntu 12.04)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does leiningen work for you - i.e. is it just boot that is failing, or is there a general problem downloading dependencies?

Comment: Hi Daniel. It is only boot that is failing. I got the pedestal framework working with Leiningen.

Comment: Hmm not sure why leiningen would be able to access maven, but boot wouldn't. Are you behind a proxy? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729023/maven-build-issue-connection-to-repository-refused

Comment: I have tried to place a settings.xml file under my .m2 directory:

Comment: <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>my_proxy</host>
      <port>my_port</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>

Comment: Similar issues here on Windows. I have proxy settings in settings.xml in.m2 folder