# I have installed maven 3.2.3 and i tried to import one project to eclipse. I got this error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to maven. Please help me to solve this

> **[ERROR]** Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom -> [Help 1]

Comment: It looks like a proxy issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729023/maven-build-issue-connection-to-repository-refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is not able download the required artifacts. Check the proxy settings in your maven `settings.xml`.  If you are using a proxy, provide the corresponding host and port details below.

```
 <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```