# Error in Project Object Model after adding my H2 dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have been trying to use H2 in memory database and tried to dds dependencies. I am getting an error in pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.emp.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeProject</name>
    <description>Employee Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Add version to h2 dependency

Comment: can you actually do mvn install or even that fails?

Comment: Getting error as 'Maven dependencies' references non existing library'

Comment: @MaciejKowalski - I am getting below error after maven install."one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.5.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.5.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]"

Comment: @SergioGragera still getting same error after adding version for h2 dependency

Comment: Try to do a telnet repo.maven.apache.org 80 and read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729023/maven-build-issue-connection-to-repository-refused

Comment: You're having a connectivity issue to maven central due to firewall/proxy or something else in your local environment. This has nothing to do with h2 and can not be viewed as general programming issue.