# mavenCentral() doesn't work when I upgrade Android Studio to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I have an android project, it worked well before.

Today I upgrade Android Studio to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, then I run the project in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, but I get the following error.

I debug the project, I think the code `mavenCentral()` cause the error, so I replace  `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()`, the app can work well.

I know that `jcenter()` is obsoleted, but why does `mavenCentral()` cause error?

**Error**

```
**Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsFreeDebugMiniKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
   > Failed to transform kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.2.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.2.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.2.0)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.2.0/kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.2.0.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.2.0/kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.2.0.jar'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Failed to transform annotations-12.0.jar (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download annotations-12.0.jar (com.intellij:annotations:12.0)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.jar'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Failed to transform guava-29.0-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download guava-29.0-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Failed to transform checker-qual-2.11.1.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.11.1) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download checker-qual-2.11.1.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.11.1)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.11.1/checker-qual-2.11.1.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.11.1/checker-qual-2.11.1.jar'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Failed to transform error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect**

*** Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.**
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: may i know why you used // before mavenCentral() ?

Comment: Android Studio displays "jcenter() is obsoleted"

Comment: you have commented out the mavenCentral. that's why it's not working. 

you should remove // and rebuild the project

Comment: Thanks! I have rebuilded the project but I still get the same error.

Comment: The output shows that the connection to maven is refused. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729023/maven-build-issue-connection-to-repository-refused

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your hosts file for references to repo.maven.apache.org?

Reason:

```
[repo.maven.apache.org/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Thanks! But  it worked well with `mavenCentral()` in Android Studio 4.2 via proxy, why do I get the errro after I upgrade to Android Studio Arctic Fox ?

Comment: Had you configured a proxy for Gradle perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy